# Stucked queries

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am using simple mysqli queries, and even if they produce no results or answer from the server gives me errors, I close the connection with mysqli_free_result command.
The problem is, that these connections are stuck sometimes and I cannot delete them in the Information_schema, because I have no access to that table.
Is there any solution using mysqli to terminate the stuck connection.

```
$query = mysqli_query( $this->link, $sql);
```

and then:

```
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *stuck connection*, can you show the errors your getting.

Comment: If you get some errors, you should provide those exact errors in the question. If you need to close the connection explicitly (which happens at the end of the script anyways), use `$this->link->close()`. `free_result()` is not doing anything to the connection.

Comment: Although your question appears to be valid your question-tag is too short and triggered community bot to send it to traige review. Please provide required information for your question-tag to make it unique instead of leaving it too general. End of triage review > requires editing.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_free_result` only frees the result's memory, according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php):

> Frees the memory associated with the result.

In your case, since the connections are "stuck", I think that means the query is taking quite a long time and there's no result returned yet, so `mysqli_free_result` won't work.

If you want to give up on waiting for the results and terminate the connection, you can use `mysqli_close(CONNECTION)` or `CONNECTION::close` (depending on how you initialized the connection) to close the mysql connection. For details refer to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php).